# Inject Javascript into selenium Python -> converted_args})['value']

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, webdriver, inject

I am trying to inject some javascript code into my chrome selenium browser. The javascript contains a token that is only valid one time and therefore the javascript can only be executed once. To inject the javascript I have used:

```
driver.execute_script(toinject)
```

Where toinject contains this javascript:

```
javascript:(function(){ var f = document.createElement("form"); f.setAttribute("id","destroyer"); f.setAttribute("method","post"); f.setAttribute("action","http://www.adidas.ch/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-CH-Site/default/Cart-MiniAddProduct?clientId=c1f3632f-6d3a-43f4-9987-9de920731dcb"); var masterPid = document.createElement("input"); masterPid.setAttribute("type","hidden"); masterPid.setAttribute("name","masterPid"); masterPid.setAttribute("value","BY9913"); var pid = document.createElement("input"); pid.setAttribute("type","hidden"); pid.setAttribute("name","pid"); pid.setAttribute("value","BY9913_620"); var ajaxOption = document.createElement("input"); ajaxOption.setAttribute("type","hidden"); ajaxOption.setAttribute("name","ajax"); ajaxOption.setAttribute("value","true"); var responseOption = document.createElement("input"); responseOption.setAttribute("type","hidden"); responseOption.setAttribute("name","layer"); responseOption.setAttribute("value","Add To Bag overlay"); var quantity = document.createElement("input"); quantity.setAttribute("type","hidden"); quantity.setAttribute("name","Quantity"); quantity.setAttribute("value","1"); var sessionSelectedStoreID = document.createElement("input"); sessionSelectedStoreID.setAttribute("type","hidden"); sessionSelectedStoreID.setAttribute("name","sessionSelectedStoreID"); sessionSelectedStoreID.setAttribute("value","null"); var captchaToken = document.createElement("input"); captchaToken.setAttribute("type","hidden"); captchaToken.setAttribute("name","g-recaptcha-response"); captchaToken.setAttribute("value","03AMPJSYXHk0axYBy3sJEKk7pSbaubS9c0Du3y87zzid05zpMpMvyzWdqRQmbPqVM2cxd9j3RNjMyX7x3_NOmo7NhlJD0YjyZlwG13AIGwHZ9E0IYqX1YyxAO162pXPxZboq4M47CA9Sf2BDdwIPjHsPgOX3ELuFeWR38Su0jsrrJoQ1ti49wllmsM3EbfSM4PXoudbary0NmXrSC2qpkQ0H3SkIbW3cfiwnDPm6s5bWlznjFAwtuDBbWGm7FC2TizgPr_nVRW4hh7E9F_lEkTWS-BIQFsan2huh7z-eK1Q1WEYUC9ReDg87GoKPF0CAz3yfanh_hbfHr7yMVSxqkQznGXmNQ-tj8gfa9PVwKM5BUT_-ofQliUBgEWePQN31cStqRxDuUesGyB"); f.appendChild(captchaToken); var captchaDuplicate = document.createElement("input"); captchaDuplicate.setAttribute("type","hidden"); captchaDuplicate.setAttribute("name","x-PrdRt"); captchaDuplicate.setAttribute("value","03AMPJSYXHk0axYBy3sJEKk7pSbaubS9c0Du3y87zzid05zpMpMvyzWdqRQmbPqVM2cxd9j3RNjMyX7x3_NOmo7NhlJD0YjyZlwG13AIGwHZ9E0IYqX1YyxAO162pXPxZboq4M47CA9Sf2BDdwIPjHsPgOX3ELuFeWR38Su0jsrrJoQ1ti49wllmsM3EbfSM4PXoudbary0NmXrSC2qpkQ0H3SkIbW3cfiwnDPm6s5bWlznjFAwtuDBbWGm7FC2TizgPr_nVRW4hh7E9F_lEkTWS-BIQFsan2huh7z-eK1Q1WEYUC9ReDg87GoKPF0CAz3yfanh_hbfHr7yMVSxqkQznGXmNQ-tj8gfa9PVwKM5BUT_-ofQliUBgEWePQN31cStqRxDuUesGyB"); f.appendChild(captchaDuplicate); var s = document.createElement("input"); s.setAttribute("type","submit"); s.setAttribute("value","Submit"); f.appendChild(masterPid); f.appendChild(pid); f.appendChild(ajaxOption); f.appendChild(responseOption); f.appendChild(quantity); f.appendChild(sessionSelectedStoreID); f.appendChild(s); document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(f); })(); document.getElementById(document.querySelector("[id^='destroyer']").id).submit();
```

It is very long but im pretty certain it is correct because it works if I run it using a javascript tester. What happens after is, the javascript seems to be executed twice, making the token invalid. I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "testin.py", line 74, in startbot
    openseission()
  File "testin.py", line 183, in openseission
    driver.execute_script(toinject)
  File "/Users/____/Desktop/going_headless/chaptcha/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 546, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "/Users/____/Desktop/going_headless/chaptcha/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 311, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/___/Desktop/going_headless/chaptcha/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 237, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: chrome=65.0.3305.0)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.34.522932 (4140ab217e1ca1bec0c4b4d1b148f3761eb3a03e),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.6 x86_64)
```

How can I avoid this? I have'nt found anyone with the same problem for the past 3 hours. I don't mind injecting the javascript another way but I don't know any. Thank you in advance

Comment: Seems the error is clear `call function result missing 'value'`. Can you check the `JS` if all the values are provided?

Answer (score 1):

Your trace suggests you are using chrome 65 (are you on the beta channel?) w/chromedriver 2.34. I don't think chrome 65 can be driven with that version of chromedriver. You might want to downgrade chrome (e.g. to the stable version, currently 63, I believe).